# Implement recursive MergerSort in Java

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I have a problem implementing merge-sort in Java. The objective is to have two classes, the first one is union, which combines two already sorted arrays (I think I got that one right). The other class, "sort" however is where I'm really stuck. I want to split an array recursively into smaller arrays and then combine them with union. Here's what I got so far, I hope there is someone who can help me... Thanks!

```
class MergeSort {
 public static int[] sort(int[] array) {

int[] firsthalf = new int[array.length];  #muss noch verschoben werden, a
System.arraycopy(array, 0, firsthalf, 0, array.length);

int[] firsthalf = Arrays.copyofRange(firsthalf, 0, lefthalf.length/2)
int[] secondhalf= Arrays.copyofRange(
public static int[] union(int[] sortedIntArray1,
                        int[] sortedIntArray2) {



int[] neuesarray = new int[sortedIntArray1.length + SortedIntArray2.length];
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
while (i < sortedIntArray1.length && j < sortedIntArray2.length)
{
    if (sortedIntArray1[i] < sortedIntArray2[j]) #wenn liste an stelle i kleiner als liste 2 an stelle j 
    {
        neuesarray[k] = sortedIntArray1[i]; 
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        answer[k] = sortedIntArray2[j];                       #bei umgekehrtem fall, wird von liste2 das element angehängt
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

while (i < sortedIntArray1.length)          #diese while schleifen sind wichtig, sonst bleibt der Zeiger praktisch stehen
{
    neuesarray[k] = sortedIntArray1[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

while (j < sortedIntArray2.length)
{
    neuesarray[k] = sortedIntArray2[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}

return neusarray;
} 
}
}
```

Comment: else
    {
        answer[k] = sortedIntArray2[j];                       #bei umgekehrtem fall, wird von liste2 das element angehängt
        j++;
    }          what is the purpose of answer[k]?

Comment: What happen when sortedIntArray1[i] == sortedIntArray2[j] ?

Comment: @SkyDream he kept that values in answer[k]. but, what is the use of that I don't know